# PHP/MySQL code fail to insert duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, json, insert-into

I have some PHP code to select data from & insert data into a MYSQL database.
Here's what I'm trying to do:
- receive a barcode serial number from a JSON payload
- connect to the MySQL database
- check a database table (passes) to see if the barcode has been registered
- if so, write this barcode + timestamp into another table (activations). Then return a JSON mssage that it was successful
- if not, return a JSON message that the barcode was not yet registered.

The code below works OK when I check a specific barcode for the first time. But after that it doesn't insert a new entry in the activations table. Instead I get the message 'Activation not recorded' ..

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks if you can help!

Andrew

```
<?php
//Messages will be returned as JSON data
header("Content-type: application/json");

//read the POST payload
$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

//get a database connection
require_once("../class/Database.php");
$db = Database::get();

//check for a valid pass
$barcode = $payload['barcode'];
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM passes WHERE barcode = ?");
$statement->execute(array($barcode));
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
  $statement2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO activations(activationDatetime, barcode)     VALUES (?,?)");
  $statement2->execute(array(date("Y-m-d G:i:s"),$barcode));
  if ($statement2->rowCount()==0) {
  print json_encode(array("msg"=>"Activation not recorded"));
  } else {
  print json_encode(array("msg"=>"Pass successfully activated"));
  }
} else 
{
  print json_encode(array("msg"=>"Pass not registered"));
  exit();
}

flush();

exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `if ($statement2->rowCount()==0) {` this statement is wrong please check. You can not use "rowCount" there as it is a insert query.

And I think, it is inserted only issue is not showing message properly.

Comment: [**PDOStatement::rowCount()** returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding ***PDOStatement*** object.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should print the sql error at the debug stage of your page.

I guess, the barcode field is uniq.

Comment: Agreed.  In the case of PDO, one can set `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)` to avoid having to manually inspect for errors (although one should be doing that anyway, at very least with exceptions - for which one can use `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`) and then fetch & output the relevant message.